# Probability of consecutive coin flips

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

There are 15 coins in a bag. 5 of the 15 are fair coins and the rest are biased (80% H, 20% T). When a coin is chosen randomly from the bag and flipped twice, what is the probability that both of them are heads?

I tried to solve this using two different ways and I get two different answers.

Method 1:
$$P_{fair}(HH) = \frac {1}{2^2}$$
Considering 80% is $\frac 45$ and 20% is $\frac 15$
$$P_{biased}(HH) = \frac {4^2}{5^2}$$
$$P(HH) = \frac {1}{3}P_{fair}(HH) + \frac {2}{3}P_{biased}(HH)$$
$$P(HH) = \frac {51}{100}$$

Method 2:
Constructing from all possible outcomes, consider 1 fair coin for every 2 biased coins.
$$P(HH) = \frac {\text{number of outcomes with two H}}{\text{total outcomes}}$$
$$\text{total outcomes} = (\text{outcomes for fair coin}) + 2(\text{outcomes for biased coin})$$
$$\text{outcomes for fair coin} = \text{\{H, T\} tossed twice}$$
$$\text{outcomes for biased coin} = \text{\{H, H, H, H, T\} tossed twice}$$
$$\text{total outcomes}=2^2+2(5^2)$$
$$=54$$
$$\text{number of outcomes with two H} = \text{HH for fair coin} + 2(\text{HH for biased coin})$$
$$=1+2(4^2)$$
$$=33$$
$$P(HH) = \frac{33}{54}$$

Have I done a mistake in either of the methods or maybe both? It's not like I didn't understand conditional probability (or did I?). For instance, I can find the probability of drawing two red cards from a deck of playing cards using both those methods.
$$P(RR) = P(Red_1) P(Red_2|Red_1)$$
$$=\frac{26}{52} \frac{25}{51}$$

Also using just combinatorics,
$$P(RR) = \frac{^{26}P_2}{^{52}P_2}$$
$$=\frac{26 \times 25}{52\times51}$$

So definitely my methods aren't incorrect. Coming back to my original question, where did I go wrong?

Comment: The first method is sound.  For the second, counting methods only work if you have equally probable events.  I'm not sure which events you are considering in that case.

Comment: The same opinion as in previous comment. The second method is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is correct.  The second one is, quite honestly, bizarre.

If you really had your heart set on trying to approach the solution in such a way, you would need to make the set of outcomes for the two coins comparable in number.  What I mean by this is that you would set up a single toss of a coin as having $2 \cdot 5 = 10$ possible outcomes.  The fair coin would randomly select between $5$ heads and $5$ tails.  The unfair coin would randomly select between $8$ heads and $2$ tails.  Then for two tosses of the fair coin would yield $5 \cdot 5 = 25$ outcomes in which both tosses are heads, and the unfair coin would yield $8 \cdot 8 = 64$ outcomes in which both tosses are heads.  Then weighting by the relative frequencies of coins of each type, this gives $1(25) + 2(64) = 153$ desired outcomes.  The denominator is simply $3(10^2) = 300$ outcomes.  And we get $\frac{153}{300} = \frac{51}{100}$, as before.

What we have essentially done is to have three piles of playing cards, each of which contains $10$ cards.  In Pile A, five cards are red and five are black.  In each of Piles B and C, eight cards are red and two are black.  You randomly select one pile, and then from that pile, you draw one card and observe the color.  You return that card to the same pile; then you draw another card from the same pile and observe the color.  The desired probability is equivalent to the probability that both cards that are drawn are red.

But I would not recommend this sort of solution, not only because it is unnecessarily tedious and confusing, but also because it does not generalize to the case where the unfair coin is biased in a way that is not a rational multiple of the fair coin's probability of heads.  Specifically, how would you proceed in the case where the unfair coin had a probability of heads of $1/\sqrt{2} \approx 0.707107$?  You could get an approximate answer using this method, but an exact answer is straightforward with the first solution method.

Comment: I understood the intuition behind three piles of 10 cards/coins each. But what made you normalize the number of outcomes in each pile?

Comment: @JohnStrood Yes, I meant $8 \cdot 8$.  As for why the number of outcomes needs to be the same for each pile (or coin), it is because you are adding together the number of desired outcomes before you divide by the total number of outcomes.  Therefore, the number of outcomes needs to correctly represent their relative occurrence.